# How to get the previous value of state in React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I have this `reducer`

```
import { FETCH_WEATHER } from "../actions/index";

export default function(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_WEATHER:
      console.log(state)
      return [action.payload.data,...state];
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

but whenever I console.log the `state` the result is always `undefined`

and here is my `action`

```
import axios from 'axios';

const API_KEY = '...';
const ROOT_URL = `...`
export const FETCH_WEATHER = 'FETCH_WEATHER';

export function fetchWeather(city){
  const url = `${ROOT_URL}&q=${city},us`;
  const request = axios.get(url)
  return {
    type : FETCH_WEATHER,
    payload: request,
  }
}
```

I'm thinking to create a constant to hold the data overall and just pass it in reducer but I don't think it's the right approach.

Question:
How can I access the previous state in the reducer so that whenever I `console.log` there is a value.

Here is the code [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jv7rxx55xv)

Comment: Are you using redux-thunk or anything similar to handle this [async action](https://redux.js.org/advanced/asyncactions)?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I'm not using redux-thunk

Comment: Have you read async action creator of link to the redux documentation? Effectively you'd need some sort of middleware to delay dispatching actions until the API call has executed/resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previous state is stored in your `state` variable, as defined in your reducer. Previous state can therefore be accessed in your reducer via the `state` variable.

It looks like you have a block syntax error that may be causing you problems (see correction below).

Also, if you want to log previous state to the console when ever your reducer is run, consider placing the call to `console.log` at the beginning of your reducer:

```
import { FETCH_WEATHER } from "../actions/index";

export default function(state = [], action) {

  // console.log(state) // Add this to log previous state for every call to reducer

  switch (action.type) {

    case FETCH_WEATHER: { // Added { here

      console.log(state)
      return [action.payload.data,...state];

    } // Added } here

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: what's the error? what are you expecting to have happen?

Comment: There's no error in the console. I'm trying to access the previous value in the state but it always return undefined

Comment: is your reducer being called? with the expected payload? add the `console.log(state)` to beginning of your reducer - what does it print?